# Unable to add new bookmarks to Mozilla Firefox's bookmark bar any more

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I imported my bookmarks from Google Chrome into Mozilla Firefox as I wanted to remove Google Chrome, and instead use Mozilla Firefox. So in my `Bookmarks Menu` section there is a folder called `Bookmarks bar`, and all of the bookmarks which I originally imported are showing in my actual bookmark bar as they should, and when I added some more new bookmarks to the folder they too appeared in my bookmarks bar, but now I have stopped being able to add stuff, well, I can add them to the `Bookmarks bar` folder in the `Bookmarks Menu` section, and they appear there when I view that folder, but they do not appear in my actual bookmarks bar.

So why is this? And how can I fix it because I am now not able for some unknown reason to actually add any more bookmarks to my bookmark bar which is rather annoying and means that I have to keep on opening the list of all my bookmarks and then finding them in there?

---

### OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

### Package Information:

```
firefox:
  Installed: 37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 37.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     37.0+build2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the bookmarks bar has a limit to the amount of bookmarks that can be on it. There's probably an arrow icon on the right that will reveal the rest of your bookmarks when clicked.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Yes, there is an arrow, but that is my point, even in that list my new bookmarks do not appear.

Comment: I think you may have filled the available space/

Comment: @Zacharee1: Is there no way to expand the available space?

Comment: Without rewriting Firefox, no. Besides, not all of those bookmarks can be frequently accessed ones.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Well, I only have bookmarks there that I go to a lot, or keep for reference, and those particular ones, I do actually go to a lot.

Comment: @Zacharee1: It's fine, I found the answer and have posted it as an answer, and will accept it tomorrow when it lets me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way. Although it is a little odd that you have to do it this way, it still works. Instead of going into the `Bookmarks bar` folder in the `Bookmarks menu` section, you instead have to click on the thing next to the star:

[image: Next to Star]

Then go to the pull-down menu called `Bookmark Toolbar`, and then you can right-click in there and paste bookmarks either from the `Unsorted Bookmarks` pull-down menu if they are new, or the other sections where you stored them if you have already moved them somewhere else. And then they should appear in the bookmarks bar.

These are the pull-down menus I mean:

[image: Firefox bookmarks pull-down menus]